# Broadcasting, laravel-echo-server not receiving events

Tags: php, laravel, broadcast

I'm using Laravel in a project and I want to use broadcasting with laravel-echo-server and Redis. I have set up both in a docker container. Output below:

`Redis`

```
    redis_1                | 1:C 27 Sep 06:24:35.521 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
    redis_1                | 1:C 27 Sep 06:24:35.577 # Redis version=4.0.2, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
    redis_1                | 1:C 27 Sep 06:24:35.577 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
    redis_1                | 1:M 27 Sep 06:24:35.635 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
    redis_1                | 1:M 27 Sep 06:24:35.635 # WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128.
    redis_1                | 1:M 27 Sep 06:24:35.635 # Server initialized
    redis_1                | 1:M 27 Sep 06:24:35.635 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
    redis_1                | 1:M 27 Sep 06:24:35.636 # WARNING you have Transparent Huge Pages (THP) support enabled in your kernel. This will create latency and memory usage issues with Redis. To fix this issue run the command 'echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled' as root, and add it to your /etc/rc.local in order to retain the setting after a reboot. Redis must be restarted after THP is disabled.
    redis_1                | 1:M 27 Sep 06:24:35.715 * DB loaded from disk: 0.079 seconds
    redis_1                | 1:M 27 Sep 06:24:35.715 * Ready to accept connections
```

A few warnings but nothing breaking.

`laravel-echo-server`

```
laravel-echo-server_1  | L A R A V E L  E C H O  S E R V E R
laravel-echo-server_1  | 
laravel-echo-server_1  | version 1.3.1
laravel-echo-server_1  | 
laravel-echo-server_1  | ⚠ Starting server in DEV mode...
laravel-echo-server_1  | 
laravel-echo-server_1  | ✔  Running at localhost on port 6001
laravel-echo-server_1  | ✔  Channels are ready.
laravel-echo-server_1  | ✔  Listening for http events...
laravel-echo-server_1  | ✔  Listening for redis events...
laravel-echo-server_1  | 
laravel-echo-server_1  | Server ready!
laravel-echo-server_1  | 
laravel-echo-server_1  | [6:29:38 AM] - dG0sLqG9Aa9oVVePAAAA joined channel: office-dashboard
```

The client seems to join the channel without any problems. 
However, if I kick of an event laravel-echo-server doesn't receive the event.

I did a bit of research and found something about a queue worker. So I decided to run that (`php artisan queue:work`) and see if that did anything. According to the docs it should run only the first task in the queue and then exit (as opposed to `queue:listen`). And sure enough it began processing the event I kicked of earlier. But it didn't stop and kept going until I killed it:

```
[2017-09-27 08:33:51] Processing: App\Events\CompanyUpdated
[2017-09-27 08:33:51] Processing: App\Events\CompanyUpdated
[2017-09-27 08:33:51] Processing: App\Events\CompanyUpdated
[2017-09-27 08:33:51] Processing: App\Events\CompanyUpdated
etc..
```

The following output showed in the redis container:

```
redis_1                | 1:M 27 Sep 06:39:01.562 * 10000 changes in 60 
seconds. Saving...
redis_1                | 1:M 27 Sep 06:39:01.562 * Background saving started by pid 19
redis_1                | 19:C 27 Sep 06:39:01.662 * DB saved on disk
redis_1                | 19:C 27 Sep 06:39:01.663 * RDB: 2 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
redis_1                | 1:M 27 Sep 06:39:01.762 * Background saving terminated with success
```

Now I either did so many api calls that the queue is so massive, or something is going wrong. Additionally, laravel-echo-server didn't show any output after the jobs were 'processed'.

I have created a hook in my Model which kicks of the event:

```
public function __construct(array $attributes = []) {
    parent::__construct($attributes);

    parent::created(function( $model ){
        //event(new CompanyCreated($model));
    });

    parent::updated(function( $model ){
        event(new CompanyUpdated($model));
    });

    parent::deleted(function( $model ){
        event(new CompanyDeleted($model));
    });
}
```

Then this is the event it kicks off:

```
class CompanyUpdated implements ShouldBroadcast {
use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

/**
 * Create a new event instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(Company $company) {
    $this->company = $company;
}

/**
 * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
 *
 * @return Channel|array
 */
public function broadcastOn() {
    return new Channel('office-dashboard');
}
}
```

And finally, this is the code on the front-end that's listening for the event:

```
window.Echo.channel('office-dashboard')
  .listen('CompanyUpdated', (e) => {
    console.log(e.company.name);
  });
```

`.env` file:

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=redis
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=redis

REDIS_HOST=redis
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

Why isn't the event passed to laravel-echo-server? Anything I'm missing or forgetting?

Comment: did you change your broadcast driver in .env?

Comment: Yes I have, I have updated my question to show the relevant bit of code from my .env

Comment: did you queue:work process something? it seems like it is failing. maybe you could try changing your queue driver to sync first to see error if ever it is not processing the queue

Comment: did you configured echo to connect to server?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but I used the docker containers. They should take care of the connecting. Anyways, when I went to continue working on it this week it began working out of the blue, I didn't even change anything. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Started working out of the blue.

Comment: Don't you ever faced same problem again? I think this is because `Echo` is not ready to subscribe when you call `window.Echo.channel().listen()`. I faced same problem so I took a look into chrome developer tool's websocket stream. `Websocket` was connected successfully but message for subscribe was not sending to `laravel-echo-server`. So I used `setTimeout` for wait 1000ms then all worked fine. What a bug

Answer (score 0):

For me, @jesuisgenial's comment pointed me in the right direction.

You can easily identify if it's not subscribing by checking the Websockets tab under the Networking tab in Chrome developer tools

**Without 1 second delay (no subscribe event):**

```
Echo.private(`users.${context.getters.getUserId}`)
    .listen('.conversations.new_message', function(data) {
        console.log(data.message);
    })
```

[image: Without delay]

**With 1 second delay (subscribe event present):**

```
setTimeout(() => {
    Echo.private(`users.${context.getters.getUserId}`)
        .listen('.conversations.new_message', function(data) {
            console.log(data.message);
        })
}, 1000)
```

[image]